# How to increase Request limits

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request, limits

We have application named [Milekeeper](http://apps.facebook.com/milekeeper/), which relays users to send invitations to race to his or hers friends.
We are sending these race participation invites to feed.

After some hardcore testing we received this error: "FbGraph::InvalidRequest OauthException :: (#341) Feed action request limits reached".

What are limits and how can we increase these????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot increase these limits.

These limits were imposed to prevent apps from spamming Facebook. If you are getting this error, it means that you are reaching the limit. You are simply not allowed to post more. These limits are expressed as "buckets" and can be viewed on the [insights page](http://www.facebook.com/insights/) for your app if you want to see how much you can post.

I think regular users will not encounter this error, unless you are actually forcing a user to publish a big number posts every day, which should be frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it made it clearer, but i just have a problem find a "buckets" on insights page. And under "View Insights" there are more or less only graphs. Can you be more sepciffic - where can i find those limits?

Comment: Go to Insights, then select your app; you'll see a menu on the left called "App insights". Click on Diagnostics. On that page you should see a section called "Feature limits", that's what you're looking for (you'll also see a section called "API throttling" and "API throttling warnings", both will give you more info too).